# Lambda Schedule to println from a ArrayList

Tags: lambda, timer, java-8, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a timer to print out from an ArrayList at a schedule. But I am receiving this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'schedule(<lambda expression>,int,java.util.concurret.TimeUnit)'
```

Why am I receiving this error and what can I do about it?

```
List<String> finalQuestionsList = questionsList;
timer.schedule(()-> finalQuestionsList.forEach(write::println),120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Check out the different signature of the method `schedule` and make sure to comply with one of them: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: `TimerTask` is not a functional interface, but you shouldn’t use that class anyway. Use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) asserts type of a lambda expression:

> A lambda expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

1. TimerTask is not a [Function Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html), so you can't assign a lambda expression  to a TimerTask. but  you can adaptee a Runnable to a TimerTask with an adapter method `task`.
2. [Timer.schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-) methods can't take a `TimeUnit`, but you can using [TimeUnit.toMills()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toMillis-long-) to convert a duration to milliseconds.
3. I can't see any `write` variable in your code snippet, so I use `System.out` instead.

   ```
   List<String> finalQuestionsList = questionsList;
   timer.schedule(task(() -> finalQuestionsList.forEach(System.out::println))
            , 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));

   private TimerTask task(Runnable task) {
       return new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
           task.run();
         }
       };
   }
   ```